# Code Signing Error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, certificate

The company I am working for has a base app that they reskin and sell to different businesses. I have redesigned the app and am trying to upload it to their account but am getting:

```
[BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any
valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

How do I add their developer account into my Xcode and acquire a certificate for distribution?

Thank you

Comment: Have you ever gone through the provisioning/distribution process before? Apple has great docs on the subject in the ios dev center / provisioning portal. You need the highest level access to do app store distributions using their account.

Comment: Your certificate might have been invalidated.  I know mine was by accident.  Delete the cert, then download/reapply for one and drag it onto Xcode to see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to have maximum privileges in the Provisioning Portal to do the following, so if you don't, get it, and then do this:

1. Login and download a **developer certificate**. If you need to create one, select **How To** from the menu in the Provisioning Portal under certificates.
2. Download a **distribution certificate**. Again, if you need one, select **How To**.
3. Open both certificates and make sure they open in your **Keychain Access**
4. Select provisioning and download both a developer and distribution .mobileprovision provisioning profile. Create one if necessary using **How To**
5. Make sure you have XCode open and open both .mobileprovisioning profiles. Make sure that they open in the Organizer and show in the status that they are properly linked with a certificate that is valid in the **Keychain Access**. *If they aren't, a flag will pop up, saying something like "There is no valid certificate associated with this profile" in bright red.*
6. Check your code signing in both the **Target** and **Project** areas of your build. Make absolutely sure that both are trying to sign using your **distribution profile**.
7. Make sure that you are building the **distribution *scheme*** of your app (You may have to create this).
8. Finally set the build device to iOS Device, set the scheme to Distribution, and select Archive. **It is imperative that when the program asks you to allow the code signing to use your private key, that you select "Allow" and not "Always Allow," as this is very buggy and often results in code signing errors.**

If you need any more help, comment.

Hope this helps!