# iOS provisioning code signing problems. How can I wipe everything out and start over?

Tags: ios, code-signing, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I am having real trouble with provisioning and code signing issues. I have migrated to a new computer and have a bunch of "Valid signing identity not found" messages. In repeated attempts to fix distribution code signing I have managed to lose my developer code signing as well.

I am the first to admit that the root problem is my **complete and utter failure** to grasp the concepts of code signing, provisioning, and all related subjects. I am asking a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970910/what-are-good-resources-other-than-apple-to-understand-certificates-code-sign) on SO to address this.

THIS question is to ask for concrete steps to wipe my provisioning and code signing mess completely clean. I am running Xcode 4.3 and have 2 live apps in the App Store that I do not want to interrupt the distribution of. Please help.

**Update:** I have imported my private key from the old mac, and it is showing in Keychain Access. When I try to request a certificate according to Apple docs, I don't get a "Let me specify key/value" checkbox, and when I try to save it to disk anyways I get the error "the specified item could not be found in the keychain". Arrgh.

Comment: [This might help](http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=IN&v=mX4v9A2bpjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1**: Open XCode. In the Organizer, delete all provisioning profiles.

**Step 2**: Open Keychain Access (Utilities>Keychain Access); delete all certificates related to developer/distribution and the WWDCCA (or whatever it's called) intermediate certificate.

**Step 3**: Re-download and resign. Make sure you export and import your private key from your old machine to your new one.

If you need instructions on how to set up code signing, you can look at my answer to this question: [Code Signing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287401/code-signing-error/9287639#9287639).

Cheers!

Comment: Slow down there, Tex. :) I have imported my original private key, and it is sitting there in Keychain Access. What do I do next?

Comment: Download both certificates (Dev/Dist) from the Provisioning Portal and open them in Keychain, then download both .mobileprovision profiles and open them in XCode (just open them) and they should attempt to link with your certificates you just imported. I outlined the entire process in the question referenced in my answer. If you need any more help, the Provisioning Portal has How To pages associated with each step of the process.

Comment: Deleting the certificates did it for me

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial here. You may find this helpful

http://seventhsoulmountain.blogspot.com/2013/09/ios-code-sign-in-complete-walkthrough.html