# xcode deploy to ipad for testing purposes

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, deployment

I am new to IOS development. I created my app on MAC and now time to test it on real device. I paid 99USD to Apple to enroll into the developer program. I followed many tutorials to deploy the app to my IPad but couldnt succeed. Here are the problems;

First, I get this `"Too Few Items In Team"` message. What does this mean?

Second, I was never be able to have a proper certificate. I did everything as tutorial says, but my certificate says `"This certificate was signed by an unknown authority"`

Because of these errors, when I run the app from Xcode while iPad is selected as deployment target, it give this error `"Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains"`

what should I do to fix these? Is there a good tutorial you could suggest?

Comment: Have a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287401/code-signing-error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171278/too-few-items-in-teams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. here are the tasks you should follow;

*please check that you login with the same Apple ID to developer.apple.com and to your Computer.To make sure, delete all daw.apple.* keychains in Keychain Access. and re-login.

*please be informed that, you can deploy your app to your testing machine in two different ways. First one is to do it through the Developer.Apple.com site, which I cannot succeed. Second one is through Xcode. Delete all the certificates, app id, provisioning profile from the developer.apple.com. Then in Xcode, click Organiser. you will see "provisioning profiles" at top left corner. Add a new profile, which will guide you all the way and it will do all necessary tasks for you.

I hope this helps. Once you figure it out, it is easy....